# How is Numix-Fluxbox style setting the font?

Tags: linux, configuration, fonts, fluxbox

I have installed [this Numix Fluxbox style](https://github.com/michael-ball/numix-fluxbox). Installation is done just by copying the Numix folder into `/usr/share/fluxbox/styles` folder.

[image]

The font is Monospace Regular.

The Fluxbox-style affects the fonts of the toolbar, clock, flubox menu title and items, and windows frame. These fonts are **THEORETICALLY** set in `/usr/share/fluxbox/style/MY-STYLE/theme.cfg` or in `~/.fluxbox/overlay`. But in none of them is a font mentioned.

The GTK2 fonts are set in `~/.gtkrc-2.0` and are overwritten by `lxappearance`. In my case it indeed was a different font, namely Cantarell. Changing the font in `lxappearance` changes the font in the whole system **except the ones set by the fluxbox theme (toobar, menu, windows)**. So, now I know how to set most programs to use Monospace if I want, in line with the fluxbox fonts.

But I still don't know how this fluxbox theme is setting its fonts. (No matter the font set for the gtk theme, the fluxbox fonts stay the same.)

Answer (score 0):

Usually the config setting for all fonts would be set in the theme.cfg file of in the theme's directory.

```
toolbar.font: dejavusans-12
toolbar.clock.font: dejavusans-12
menu.title.font: dejavusans-bold-11
menu.frame.font: dejavusans-bold-10
window.font: dejavusans-bold-11
```

Since you don't have this setting it will use on the default font.
Depending on your X config or GTK+ config, you can trace the default font.

Comment: There is no configuration for fonts in the theme.cfg of  numix-fluxbox - as you can see. But I don't think that is the default font, as I cannot see it anywhere else on my system: looking to the fonts used by the file manager, the menus of various programs, etc.  they are all the same, but different than the one I talk about here. It is exclusevely the items that use the Fluxbox style which have that font: that is, only the window decorations, the right-click menu on the desktop and the toolbar.

Comment: Also, if by theme you mean the fluxbox style (in this case Numix-Fluxbox) by no means is this style setting the fonts of the entire system: as you say, it's just the toolbar, clock, flubox menu title and items and windows frame. I think I have identified the font:  Monospace Regular. But that is not my system font (the one in pamanfm e.g)

Comment: "Since you don't have this setting it will use on the default font. " You mean the gtk2 font (in `~/.gtkrc-2.0`) or a different one? The default gtk2 font was Cantarell. But that affects only programs like PCManFM and Firefox, not the fonts of he  fluxbox style mentioned above.